# Xcode 6 NSCollectionView Bug?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode-6.2

I am trying to use an NSCollectionView for the first time so I go straight to the Apple Documentation [Quick Start for Collection Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CollectionViews/Introduction/Introduction.html) but it seems to fail every time. My first attempt I converted the code to Swift as I went and thought that it was just a conversion error on my behalf. The second attempt was by using the above tutorial and this great [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw-sHMTsMVs) but still trying to convert to Swift. The third attempt was pure Objective C and following the Apple Quick Start word for word, even copy & pasting all of the code and this still failed.

My question here i guess is is there a bug in XCode 6.2 or am I just missing something silly?

Is it worth attempting this in code?

I am not getting any errors, however the details view remains blank where the Cells should be. No need to add code as it is copied directly from the Apple link above. IB stuff was followed word for word as well.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: what kind of error are you getting, show us your code

Comment: No error at all. Sorry I should have stated what result I am getting. I have updated the question